# Why space usage is 0 although I had already inserted >40k rows

Tags: cassandra

Currently, I have 3 nodes for Cassandra.

I create a table named `events`

After inserting >40k rows, I perform the following command in each node.

```
nodetool -h localhost cfstats
```

This is the output from one of the node

```
Table: events
    SSTable count: 0
    Space used (live): 0
    Space used (total): 0
    Space used by snapshots (total): 43516
    Off heap memory used (total): 0
    SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.0
    Number of keys (estimate): 1
    Memtable cell count: 102675
    Memtable data size: 4224801
    Memtable off heap memory used: 0
    Memtable switch count: 1
    Local read count: 0
    Local read latency: NaN ms
    Local write count: 4223
    Local write latency: 0.085 ms
    Pending flushes: 0
    Bloom filter false positives: 0
    Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
    Bloom filter space used: 0
    Bloom filter off heap memory used: 0
    Index summary off heap memory used: 0
    Compression metadata off heap memory used: 0
    Compacted partition minimum bytes: 0
    Compacted partition maximum bytes: 0
    Compacted partition mean bytes: 0
    Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
    Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
    Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
    Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
```

To my surprise, `Space used (live)` and `Space used (total)` are 0. The other nodes are also having 0 `Space used (live)` and `Space used (total)`.

However, when I perform SELECT, I can get multiple rows which are being inserted previously.

May I know, why are my `Space used (live)` and `Space used (total)` 0 for all nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Memtables have not yet flushed to disk. Flush is generally triggered by a few things:

- The memtable reaching the max threshold size
- A commit log segment responsible for data in that memtable expiring
- User calling nodetool flush

If you insert 40k rows and then do nothing, as long as they fit comfortably in memory, they will stay in memory. You will see no permanent disk usage for those rows since there is no on-disk sstable holding their values.

The persistence for those rows is guaranteed by the commit-log, which stores mutations in the order in which they occurred on the disk and can be replayed in case of node failure. The commit-log is a rolling log so when commit-log segement is about to expire, Cassandra will flush the memtable holding the data in that segement to an on-disk sstable.

Comment: Yup. You're right. After I insert 10 millions rows, I can see non-zero Space used (live) and Space used (total)